# Association name conflicts with method in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Hi I am a beginner with rails and setting up a database/model with various associations.

I want my `transactions` controller to save to the DB both the `transactions` record and the corresponding `subtransactions` records (i.e. one row for each subtransaction (e.g. product) in the transaction).

After creating a new table `subtransactions` (associated with `transactions`), I got the following exception:

**ArgumentError in TransactionsController#create**

```
You tried to define an association named transaction on the model Subtransaction, 
but this will conflict with a method transaction already defined
by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.
```

I'm a bit confused about what this tells me, or more specifically where to look for the mistake. Not sure how to find out what method my association is conflicting with.

Comment: order is one of default methods in active record. (order in sql) http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Comment: Ok, I changed the names for the purpose of this question. Let me change it back sothat it is less confusing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message says, the problem is your transaction association: there is already an instance method on active record objects called `transaction`.

Creating an association called `transaction` also creates a reader method of the same name which would shadow the pre-existing method. In the past this would lead to really obscure errors when some internal bit of rails tried to call a method and ended up calling your association reader method instead, so rails stops you doing this.

Also, you cannot create a new method called `transaction` because `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` is a reserved method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. After doing some digging I now realise that `transaction` is a default ActiveRecord method name in rails. Clearly I should change my model name.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is because of mistake in name of your model for product_orders table

by default name should be

```
 ProductOrder
```

Comment: Apologies, I changed the names for the purpose of this question (thought this would make it easier to understand). See my updated post for the actual names